have mui icons in a dictonary using map to go through a dict and use the mui icons
When I try to use the dictionary from the JavaScript file and apply the map function to the categories, I encounter an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on the first line of the dictionary. If I convert it into a string, the error goes away, but the icons don't load. Can't I use rea tags as values?
import MusicNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MusicNote';
import {HomeIcon} from '@mui/icons-material';
import CodeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Code';
import OndemandVideoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/OndemandVideo';
import SportsEsportsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SportsEsports';
import LiveTvIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LiveTv';
import SchoolIcon from '@mui/icons-material/School';
import FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FaceRetouchingNatural';
import CheckroomIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Checkroom';
import GraphicEqIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GraphicEq';
import TheaterComedyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/TheaterComedy';
import FitnessCenterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FitnessCenter';
import DeveloperModeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeveloperMode';

export const logo = 'https://i.ibb.co/s9Qys2j/logo.png';

export const categories = [
  { name: 'New', icon: <HomeIcon /> },
  { name: 'JS Mastery', icon: <CodeIcon />, },
  { name: 'Coding', icon: <CodeIcon />, },
  { name: 'ReactJS', icon: <CodeIcon />, },
  { name: 'NextJS', icon: <CodeIcon />, },
  { name: 'Music', icon: <MusicNoteIcon /> },
  { name: 'Education', icon: <SchoolIcon />, },
  { name: 'Podcast', icon: <GraphicEqIcon />, },
  { name: 'Movie', icon: <OndemandVideoIcon />, },
  { name: 'Gaming', icon: <SportsEsportsIcon />, },
  { name: 'Live', icon: <LiveTvIcon />, },
  { name: 'Sport', icon: <FitnessCenterIcon />, },
  { name: 'Fashion', icon: <CheckroomIcon />, },
  { name: 'Beauty', icon: <FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon />, },
  { name: 'Comedy', icon: <TheaterComedyIcon />, },
  { name: 'Gym', icon: <FitnessCenterIcon />, },
  { name: 'Crypto', icon: <DeveloperModeIcon />, },
];

export const demoThumbnailUrl = 'https://i.ibb.co/G2L2Gwp/API-Course.png';
export const demoChannelUrl = '/channel/UCmXmlB4-HJytD7wek0Uo97A';
export const demoVideoUrl = '/video/GDa8kZLNhJ4';
export const demoChannelTitle = 'JavaScript Mastery';
export const demoVideoTitle = 'Build and Deploy 5 JavaScript & React API Projects in 10 Hours - Full Course | RapidAPI';
export const demoProfilePicture

use this js file in the sidebar components
import React from "react";
import { Button, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { categories } from "../utils/constants";




const Sidebar = () => {
const selectedCategory = 'New';
  return (
    <Stack
    direction="row"
    sx={{
      overflowY: "auto",
      height: { sx: "auto", md: "95%" },
      flexDirection: { md: "column" },
    }}
  >
    {categories.map((category) => (
      <button
        className="category-btn"
        onClick={() => {}}
        style={{
          background: category.name === selectedCategory && "#FC1503",
          color: "white",
        }}
        key={category.name}
      >
        <span style={{ color: category.name === selectedCategory ? "white" : "red", marginRight: "15px" }}>
          {category.icon}
        </span>
        <span style={{ opacity: category.name === selectedCategory ? "1" : "0.8" }}>
          {category.name}
        </span>
      </button>
    ))}
  </Stack>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;


